# Using TSQL and XQuery to extract values from XML

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xquery

I have a table with an XML column. Some of the XML is very large (8MB) but I'll present a simpler version of the problem here. Overall, I need to update the table and find those rows where the XML contains a node named `<CompressedPart>` at a known point in the XML tree, take its value, base64-decode it and replace `<CompressedPart>` with the resulting data.

This question is simply just the first part of that, which is trying to extract the text under a point in the XML tree. I've encountered XQuery once before and it just as life-destroying as it appears to be now.

To this end, I've simplified the XML to just two nodes thus:

```
<GovTalkMessage xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope">
    <EnvelopeVersion>2.0</EnvelopeVersion>
</GovTalkMessage>
```

and I'm simply trying to get the value "2.0". The code I'm using is:

```
SELECT  CAST('<GovTalkMessage xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope">
            <EnvelopeVersion>2.0</EnvelopeVersion>
        </GovTalkMessage>' AS XML).value('(/GovTalkMessage/EnvelopeVersion)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
```

but this returns NULL. I've tried removing/adding forward slashes, removing the [1] (which gives the incredible un-useful error message "requires a singleton"). Whatever I specify in the XQuery I just get NULL or an error.

In time I will want to select across the whole table, as below, so I'm not just looking for a solution that works for a single XML variable in the FROM clause as I've seen in other examples. This type of thing:

```
SELECT  GOVTALK_XML_INPUT_DATA.value('(/GovTalkMessage/EnvelopeVersion)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM    dbo.IndividualSubmission
```

How do I go about querying to solve just this first part of my issue?

Comment: XML has namespaces. Your current XQuery for `/GovTalkMessage/EnvelopeVersion` is using the anonymous namespace so won't match any elements in the `http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope` namespace. You either need to declare that namespace in your XQuery, see [value() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type), or use [`with xmlnamespaces`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/with-xmlnamespaces) and namespace prefixes of your choosing.

Comment: Ah, thank you. If I remove the namespace from the example it now works, which narrows it down to what the problem is.

Comment: Looking at the structure of the XML that I'm having to analyse, it has this tree structure (i.e. two namespaces). I've been led to believe that the CompressedPart will have a different namespace too when extacted. Is there a way to get XQuery to completely ignore namespaces?

<GovTalkMessage xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope">
 <Body>
  <IRenvelope xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/taxation/PAYE/RTI/EarlierYearUpdate/14-15/1">
   <EarlierYearUpdate>
    <CompressedPart Type="gzip">H4sIAAA... (and a lot of base64 encoded data)

Comment: As an addendum, we will get a new lower level (at IRenvelope level) namespace every year. Is there a way to make the query future namespace proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple ways..

```
DECLARE @X XML = '
<GovTalkMessage xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope">
    <EnvelopeVersion>2.0</EnvelopeVersion>
</GovTalkMessage>';

SELECT @X.value('(//*:EnvelopeVersion/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)');
```

Or..

```
DECLARE @X VARCHAR(1000) = '
<GovTalkMessage xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope">
    <EnvelopeVersion>2.0</EnvelopeVersion>
</GovTalkMessage>';

SELECT CAST(@X AS XML).value('(//*:EnvelopeVersion/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)');
```

Comment: Just to confirm, the * is matching any namespace?

Comment: Thats correct. There is syntex for defining the namespace but i was being lazy.